# maven-plugin-testing-harness outdated? causes Dependency convergence error

Tags: java, maven, plugins

I wrote a maven plugin and now want to test it
using maven-plugin-testing-harness,
seemingly newest version 3.3.0.
The enforcer plugin indicates that it dependency to junit 3.8.1! Very old.
Me i am using quite old stuff junit 4.12.
I dont want to downgrade.

There are other dependencies which seem also quite old.

Is this all an indication not to use the test harness at all?
If so, what are the alternatives?